# Meteor Collectionfs, how to save all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, collectionfs

I want to save all my images in a imageStore, saving, uploading and so on works fine, just this "little" problem. With this code, i go through all images and want to save them.

```
jQuery('img').each(function () {
   FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
      });
   });
 });
```

The Problem, I'm getting all images as an image, not as a file but the insertion method need files. So how can i convert my image to a file ?